# Как отправить POST запрос из PHP?

Tags: post, php, http

Грубо говоря есть такая ситуация:

- пользователь со страницы **edit.php** и POST данными отправляется на **do.php**
- в **do.php** данные обрабатываются, отправляем обратно путем `Header("Location: edit.php");`

Можно ли как-то приклеить POST данные?

P.S> GET приклеиваются легко, что-то типа `Header("Location: edit.php?data=mydata");` но POST бы подошёл лучше тк некешируемо и невидно в строке. Погуглил: пишут про CURL и про косячную реализацию. Говорят хранить в SESSION или в куках но мне бы подошёл идеально именно POST. Мб ест варианты без CURL?

Comment: Ответы на твои вопросы здесь: http://docs.php.net/manual/ru/context.http.php
и подробное разъяснение здесь: http://habrahabr.ru/post/48726/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Есть очень простое решение, даже может показаться что оно не правильное из-за его простоты.
На второй странице создаете форму по типу

```
<form action="URL" name="myform">
<input type="hidden" value="<?=$_POST['value']?>" />
</form>
```

а ниже по ходу кода прописать

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.forms["myform"].submit();
</script>
```

Но лучше использовать сессии для передачи данных между PHP скриптами. Плюсы на лицо

1. не надо изобретать велосипед для плаванья
2. так везде делают и удобно
3. проще работать
4. не грузит сервер и голову разработчика

Comment: Очень оригинально! Спасибо!

Comment: На этой страничке лучше сделать объявление по центру Аля:

"Вы будете автоматически перенаправлены на {страница} через {время} секунд"

Answer (score 2):

Я бы все же на странице **do.php** делал сериализацию данных которые переданы POST запросом, результат сериализации записал бы в сессию и после перенаправления на страницу **edit.php** разбирал и подставлял данные в нужные места.